# Select Timeout With 2 Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I've got the following View, called ViewGoods:

```
SELECT     
G.Gid, 
SI.[$Id] AS FirstSiteInId, 
SI.Date AS FirstSiteInDate, 
SI.Comments AS FirstSiteInComments, 
S.[$Id] AS FirstSiteId, 
S.[$Refex] AS FirstSiteRefex, 
SI.Client AS ClientId, 
C.[$Refex] AS ClientRefex, 
CASE WHEN SI.Contract IS NULL THEN (SELECT Contract.[$Id]
                                    FROM StockType AS ST 
                                    INNER JOIN StockTypeContract AS STC ON ST.[$Id] = STC.[$ParentId] 
                                    INNER JOIN Contract ON STC.Contract = Contract.[$Id]
                                    WHERE ST.[$Id] = VGST.StockType 
                                    AND SI.Date >= STC.StartDate)
                                    ELSE SI.Contract END AS Contract, 
CASE WHEN SI.Contract IS NULL THEN (SELECT Contract.[$Refex]
                                    FROM StockType AS ST 
                                    INNER JOIN StockTypeContract AS STC ON ST.[$Id] = STC.[$ParentId] 
                                    INNER JOIN Contract ON STC.Contract = Contract.[$Id]
                                    WHERE ST.[$Id] = VGST.StockType 
                                    AND SI.Date >= STC.StartDate) 
                                    ELSE CT.[$Refex] END AS ContractRefex, 
CASE WHEN COALESCE (Q.Quantity, 0) > 0 THEN L.SiteId ELSE NULL END AS SiteId, 
CASE WHEN COALESCE (Q.Quantity, 0) > 0 THEN L.SiteRefex ELSE NULL END AS SiteRefex, 
CASE WHEN COALESCE (Q.Quantity, 0) > 0 THEN L.Lid ELSE NULL END AS Lid, 
ISNULL(W.Weight, VGSA.Weight * Q.Quantity) AS Weight, 
COALESCE (Q.Quantity, 0) AS Quantity, 
VGSA.Article, 
VGSA.ArticleName, 
VGST.StockType, 
VGST.StockTypeRefex
FROM dbo.Goods AS G 
INNER JOIN dbo.SiteIn AS SI ON G.SiteIn = SI.[$Id] 
INNER JOIN dbo.Client AS C ON C.[$Id] = SI.Client 
INNER JOIN dbo.Site AS S ON SI.Site = S.[$Id] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Contract AS CT ON SI.Contract = CT.[$Id] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewGoodsLocation AS L ON G.Gid = L.Gid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewGoodsWeight AS W ON G.Gid = W.Gid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewGoodsQuantity AS Q ON G.Gid = Q.Gid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewGoodsSingleArticle AS VGSA ON G.Gid = VGSA.Gid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewGoodsStockType AS VGST ON VGST.Gid = G.Gid
```

When querying that View with the parameter Client or the parameter Lid, individually, everything runs well.
But if I try to mix the two of them, the View times out with no results.
Below is the query getting the timeout:

```
SELECT [t0].[Gid], [t0].[FirstSiteInId], [t0].[FirstSiteInDate], [t0].[FirstSiteInComments], [t0].[FirstSiteId], [t0].[FirstSiteRefex], [t0].[ClientId], [t0].[ClientRefex], [t0].[Contract], [t0].[ContractRefex], [t0].[SiteId], [t0].[SiteRefex], [t0].[Lid], [t0].[Weight], [t0].[Quantity], [t0].[Article], [t0].[ArticleName], [t0].[StockType], [t0].[StockTypeRefex]
FROM [ViewGoods] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Lid] IS NOT NULL) AND (([t0].[ClientId]) = 70)
```

Where have I gone wrong?

EDIT: I included here the Actual Execution Plan http://pastebin.com/PMY0aLE1 .

Comment: Have you had a look at the execution plan of the selection query? It will sometimes give good tips on missing indexes

Comment: I second Martin Smith's comment to swap out the view references with the actual queries they contain and then optimize the query.  It's counter-intuitive from a procedural/OO programming perspective, but this is a SET based land...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Query plan you posted it seems to be accessing 10 tables

Article, Client, Contract, Goods, GoodsArticle, GoodsEvent, Site, SiteIn, StockType, StockTypeContract

Are all of these actually required for your results or are any of them just artefacts of being in a view that you happen to be joining on?

There are 25 root nodes in the plan for these 10 tables so definitely some tables are being accessed more than once and it seems in quite a wasteful way.

You can see in this portion of the plan (Adds up to 40% of the cost) GoodsEvent seems to be accessed three times. I'm pretty sure if you get rid of the views that you will be able to consolidate this.

[Portion of plan http://img245.imageshack.us/img245/4105/executionplan.png](http://img245.imageshack.us/img245/4105/executionplan.png)

I think at the moment this bit of the plan is doing something like this

```
SELECT Query3.Gid, Query3.SiteId, Query3.Lid, Query3.Expr1017
FROM 
(
SELECT 
     Gid,
     SUM(CASE WHEN Type ='SO' THEN -Quantity ELSE Quantity END) AS Expr1017
FROM GoodsEvent
WHERE Type IN('AQ','SI','SO') AND IsDeleted = 0
GROUP BY Gid
) Query1
JOIN
(
SELECT 
     Gid,
     MAX(EventOn) AS Expr1014
FROM GoodsEvent
WHERE IsDeleted = 0
GROUP BY Gid
) Query2 ON Query1.GID = Query2.GID
JOIN
(
SELECT 
GoodsEvent.Gid, 
GoodsEvent.EventOn, 
GoodsEvent.SiteId, 
GoodsEvent.Lid
FROM GoodsEvent WHERE IsDeleted = 0
) Query3 ON Query3.gid=Query2.gid AND Query3.EventOn = Query2.Expr1014
```

It might be worth testing whether this is semantically equivalent and performs any better

```
;WITH X AS
(
SELECT Gid,  
       SiteId, 
       Lid, 
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Gid ORDER BY EventOn DESC) AS RN,
       Type
FROM GoodsEvent
WHERE IsDeleted = 0
) 
SELECT Gid,SiteId, Lid, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type ='SO' THEN -Quantity ELSE Quantity END) 
       OVER(PARTITION BY Gid) AS Expr1017,
FROM X WHERE RN=1 AND Type IN('AQ','SI','SO')
```

Comment: What do you suggest me to do? These views are being called because they filter information about what goods are available to the clients and also what events did they generate.

Comment: We suggest you stop using the views period.

Comment: @Hallaghan At the moment that query plan is extremely complex. I would suspect that if you just start again and write the query against the base tables you will be able to simplify things quite a lot. Without knowing your data and what the desired semantics are its difficult for me to suggest specific improvements though.

Answer (score 1):

Views should never reference other views if you want performance. This is just out and out poor design. You should not be using a view to do this. When you do this it has to completely materialize those views first before it can create the records set. So for maybe 200 final records you possibly have to callup severall billion. This will slow things down tremendously and I have found when people use this techinique that if you follow through the views all the way down to the bottom you are often calling the same data from the same table many, many times. Do NOT use a view this way. If you must use a view, then access the tables directly and do not call other views. This is a road you do not want to go down, we almost lost a mulimillion $ customer becasue someone designed this way instead of using good data access methosds.

This is a guaranteed, no way to fix it performance problem that will cause you database to eventually come to a screeching halt. It is BAD design period and must be changes as soon as humanly possible.

Answer (score 0):

Uh oh......

I can see in your view definition that you are joining to at least 9 other data structures, that appear to be views as well (so there could be further table joins within these).

This is probably not the answer you are going to want to hear but if you need to join this many data structures together then something has gone wrong at design time.

My suggestion is that you go back to the drawing board and rethink the design of this database.

**Edit: Additional thoughts..**

Consider that when you are performing queries that regularly require you to join multiple tables, these are candidates for Indexed Views i.e. materialized structures, which are effectively tables. Regularly performing large numbers of join operations results in poor performing queries with limited scalability.

Keep in mind that Normalization is the starting point for good database design, it should not necessarily be your end point.

Comment: Well, I didn't design this view or the project altogether, I'm just bug fixing this the application using this database. Going back to the drawing board isn't an option anymore here, at least they say so.

Comment: I disagree - join if necessary, because that's what's required in a normalized database.  But layering views on top of one another is definitely a recipe for poor performance and maintenance - good catch there.

Comment: I agree with you Ponies, but I'm not the one in charge here. I can only do what I'm told. I just give maintenance to the application.

Comment: @Hallaghan - When you look at the query plan is the same table being accessed multiple times? If so can you rewrite the query to look at the base tables without the views? A simple example of how this can improve things is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222542/is-querying-on-views-slower-than-doing-one-query/3222905#3222905

Comment: I included the actual execution plan above on my main post.