# SQL Queries, execution plans and "Parallelism"

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

So I'm (still) going through some slow legacy sql views used to do calculate some averages and standarddeviations on a (sometimes) large set of data. What I end up with are views joining views joining views etc.

So I though I would review the execution plan for my query. And it immediately suggested a missing index, which I then implemented. But it's still unbearably slow (so slow it times out the VB6 app querying it for data ;) )

So upon studying the execution plan further, I see that what costs the most (about 8% each in my case) are "Paralellism" cases. Mostly "Distribute Streams" and "Repartition Streams". What are these?

Comment: I worked on a similar system a few years back with Views joining on Views and where performance eventually became unacceptable as the amount of data in the system grew. I found that rewriting the queries from scratch to access the base tables rather than the Views gave orders of magnitude improvement in query cost. You'll probably find if you look at the plans that the same base tables are being accessed repeatedly to do different aggregations. [Example of Inefficiency that can arise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222542/is-querying-on-views-slower-than-doing-one-query/3222905#3222905)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Distribute Streams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189914.aspx) and [Repartion Streams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190783.aspx) are operations that occur when the SQL optimizer chooses to use [Parallel Query Processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178065.aspx). If you suspect that this is causing an issue with your query, you can force SQL Server to only use one CPU with the MAXDOP [query hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx), as illustrated below.

```
select *
    from sys.tables
    option (maxdop 1)
```

Comment: I don't know.. I just see that these operations has the highest cost in the execution plan...

Comment: Right, that's why Joe's saying if they're costing the most, try using maxdop 1 and see if your overall query performance improves.